# MSSQL Full Text search - Search only part of table rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, full-text-search

Is there a way to limit the search to specific rows in a table.

For Example:

On a big table I want to search only on rows with a specific Company ID:

```
select *
from Actions
where Company_ID=1253
and  CONTAINS(ItemDesc, 'ABC')


SELECT
    AC.*,    
    col1.RANK
FROM Actions AC
INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(Actions, ItemDesc, 'ABC',50) as col1  
    on col1.[KEY] = AC.ActionId
where Company_ID=1253
```

I tried both examples and I think the search runs first on all the table rows,
and then it filters by Company_ID

I'm looking for a way to limit the row number before search

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How does something like this behave?

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM Actions
    WHERE Company_ID = 1253
) AS CompanyFilteredActions
WHERE CONTAINS(ItemDesc, 'ABC')
```

You'd need to look at query plans and performance, but I think this will at least do what you ask.